# How can I create a custom email sender file in Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, email, send

I created a custom contact form in JavaScript which collects data in JSON.
I would like to pass it via HTTP POST to a PHP file which should format the email and just send it, but I can't find the file via the **Ajax** call because I get a 404 error.

Is there a correct way to do this?

If I put it in the root directory I can access it, but it does not receive POST data.

This is how I'm trying to pass data to my custom file which now is in: `/wp-content/themes/themeName/customMailer.php`

Angular 1 -

```
$http.post(
    '<?php echo get_site_url();?>/customMailer.php',
    $scope.FormData
).then(
    function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }, 
    function(){
       console.log("error");
    }
);
```

Comment: This is how you use ajax in WordPress https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins, checkout out and try to create a working solution, then if you're having troube we can help you improve the code.

Comment: This `'<?php echo get_site_url();?>/customMailer.php'` results in `'https://www.your-site.com/customMailer.php'` which as you may already guess isn't the right path to your custom PHP file, hence the reason why you're getting a 404 (not found) error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved moving my PHP code inside the *functions.php* file of Wordpress, and creating a function which had inside my code that sends the email.

Then I created two hooks to my php function with `add_action()` (method of wordpress).

In my Angular code I added on submit an Ajax call that makes a POST to admin-ajax.php, with a variable called "action" that has a value representing the name of my php funcion before created in *functions.php*.